# CoordinatorLayout with RecyclerView And Collapsing header

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, androiddesignsupport

I have a layout like the following:

[image]

(Toolbar,
Header View, Text View, RecyclerView)

I need the header to be collapsed when I scrolling recyclerview's items.
So that the view "Choose item" and recyclerview left on the screen.

I saw examples when toolbar is being collapsed, but I need toolbar to be present always.

Which layouts/behavior should I use to get this work?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can achieve it by having this layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <!-- HEADER -->
            <RelativeLayout
                ...
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
                .....
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

       <!-- IF YOU WANT TO KEEP "Choose Item" always on top of the RecyclerView, put this TextView here
        <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="bottom"
             android:text="choose item" />
       -->
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You pin your toolbar by having the `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` property set. You make `RecyclerView` properly scrollable  by setting `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` and that's pretty much it.

**NB!** Position of "Choose item" `TextView` depends on the particular behaviour you want to achieve:

- you can include it as a first element of your `RecyclerView`'s `Adapter` to scroll it away, once user start scrolling through the `RecyclerView`;
- you can add it into `AppBarLayout` so it will always stick on top of the `RecyclerView`, whenever you scroll it or not;

You can read more here [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and here [Design Support Library (III): Coordinator Layout](http://antonioleiva.com/coordinator-layout/)

I hope, it helps!

Comment: Will it still work, if we add a scrollview or NestedScrollView instead of recyclerview at the bottom. I am also thinking of having multiple recyclerviews inside the scrollview with sticky headers. Will that work?

Comment: I wish I found this solution early, It's working perfectly. you still save my time. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The below code is working but not smooth scroll compare reqular recyclerview I thought.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <com.sliderbanner.views.BannerSlider
                android:id="@+id/banner_slider1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:animateIndicators="true"
                app:defaultIndicators="dash"
                app:interval="5000"
                app:loopSlides="true"

                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_github"
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                    android:text="Banner Slider"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```