# Coordinator layout - collapsing content interaction with recycler view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uembe.png)

As shown in the picture, I want my 2 views ( recycler view and collapsing content ) to be responding only to the middle grip bar ( it could be 50dp height constraint layout - for example )
Moving this bar should collapse the upper part - and make recyclerview change its height. The bar shouldn't be able to move lower than the upper part content. Recycler view should be able to scroll independently all the time.

How to make only restricted area respond to touch events?
How to make recyclerview height depend on grip position ?

Now in my case, the collapsing part is getting hidden just after i start scrolling recyclerview.

If there is not enough information, I'll add whatever required.

### Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/activityToDo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.ToDoActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                        android:hint="Note title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/noteTitle"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:inputType="text" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
                <EditText
                        android:hint="Note priority"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/notePriority"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:inputType="number" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="197dp"
                    android:id="@+id/guideline"/>

                <EditText
                        android:hint="Note description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/noteDescription"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notePriority"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>
                <Button
                        android:text="Save"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline" android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/noteDescription"/>
                <Button
                        android:text="Clear"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/clearButton"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/noteDescription"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <TextView
                android:text="All notes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/allNotesRecyclerView"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/elpablosso/ToDoApplication/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_todo.xml)

Answer (score 0):

in my case like this :
add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` on your recyclerview and look my CollapsingToolbarLayout and my Toolbar

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".myactivity.DetailWisataActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_bg_detail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_beach"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                tools:targetApi="m" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorTransparantBlackLow" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_detail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_detail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/actionBarSizeLow"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:title="@string/info_wisata" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

   ............Your recyclerview here.......

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and remove your Linearlayout.

Comment: Its exact same result as i have. Doesnt fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

With the newest version of Android Studio ([4.0 Canary 9](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)), you can use the new [MotionLayout layout type](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout) to transition between different ConstraintLayouts. The simplest solution (below) wouldn't necessarily let you change the RecyclerView height to whatever you wanted, but you could smoothly transition between two different layouts when the user swipes up or down.

In short, you would do the following:

1. In your build.gradle (Module: app) file, add the following line:

   `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'`
2. Create a new ConstraintLayout layout file that determines how all of your views should be arranged at the beginning
3. Convert that ConstraintLayout to a MotionLayout using the right-click menu in the layout editor
   [image]
4. In the MotionLayout editor, add constraints to each view in the "start" and "end" layouts
   [image]
5. In the new MotionScene XML file that was added to the XML folder in your res folder, edit the  tag to look like this:

```
<Transition
      motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
      motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
       >
       <OnSwipe               
                app:touchAnchorSide="top"
                motion:touchAnchorId="@id/YOUR_GRIP_VIEW"
                motion:dragDirection="dragUp" />
           <KeyFrameSet>
           </KeyFrameSet>
 </Transition>
```

* In the [MotionLayout Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/motion-layout/#3), it says to use *app:touchAnchorID* instead of *motion:touchAnchorId* but that didn't work for me *

Now, when you swipe your grip view up or down, the MotionLayout can transition between states.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt remove your `LinearLayout` from parent of `recyclerview` and **try this:**

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <!-- HEADER -->
            <RelativeLayout
                ...
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
                .....
            </RelativeLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

       <!-- IF YOU WANT TO KEEP "Choose Item" always on top of the RecyclerView, put this TextView here
        <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="bottom"
             android:text="choose item" />
       -->
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Same question answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978250/coordinatorlayout-with-recyclerview-and-collapsing-header)