# Recyclerview with collapsable "header" in a fragment below an AppBarLayout which is in the activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using navigation graph and have a fragment with a recyclerview. My app has an ActionBar in the activity, seen in all fragments but in this one fragment I want a collapsable section above the recyclerview and below the actionbar for the search filter. Right now nothing in the filter area is clickable. I have looked for [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978250/coordinatorlayout-with-recyclerview-and-collapsing-header) but they always seem to include the appbar as well.

[image]

My current code looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".RequestTokenFragment">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorLightGray">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_requesttokens_searchtext"
                            android:layout_width="200dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:hint="Search"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="16dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_requesttokens_search"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@id/et_requesttokens_searchtext"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/et_requesttokens_searchtext"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/et_requesttokens_searchtext"
                            android:paddingStart="10dp"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"/>

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/cb_requesttokens_onlymine"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/et_requesttokens_searchtext"
                            android:text="Show only my requests or up-votes"
                            android:checked="false"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_requestedtokens_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_token_request"/>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_requestedtokens_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:contentDescription="@string/request_token" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RMp6hg1nvMIO98SqmvE2tdmgCokXgMfx/view?usp=sharing)?

Here is that code, you can modify it to make it appropriate in your use case. The thing here is to use AppBarLayout to contain the toolbar and header. Then you use `app:layout_scrollFlags` and `app:layout_behavior` to define the scrolling behavior.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        tools:context=".ui.fragment.ProductItemFragment">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingVertical="4dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgProductItem"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/img_product_ava_des"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imgProductItem"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvPriceCurrency"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                            android:text="@string/price_currency"
                            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                            android:textSize="24sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/default_text_placeholder"
                            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                            android:textSize="24sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvProductItemRate"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/default_text_placeholder"
                                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                                android:textColor="#ACA5A5" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="12dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/img_product_rate_icon_des"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_star" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvProductItemReview"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/default_text_placeholder"
                                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                                android:textColor="#ACA5A5" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="12dp"
                                android:layout_height="12dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/img_product_reviews_quantities_icon_des"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_comment" />
                        </LinearLayout>


                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/productItemTabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                app:tabPaddingBottom="8dp"
                app:tabPaddingTop="8dp" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/productItemPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```